# Tool to tie implemented autotests with software requirements

Tags: software-development, unit-tests, software-testing

Does anyone know of any tool that would let me tie autotests with software requirements and produce something like test coverage? ie. what requirements are covered with which tests, which requirements are not covered, notify when new requirements are added etc. We are using [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/) stack, so a plugin recommendation for that would be most appreciated.